# A single column has many values per row, separated by a comma. How to create an individual column for each of these?

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data-cleaning, preprocessing

As you can see below, I have a column called `code` with multiple values per row, separated by a comma. How can I create a column for each of these codes and make them all binary values?

i.e. `code6254`, `code5854` etc...., where all these columns will be of binary value `0` or `1` depending on whether that row has the code or not? Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Are the values in that column strings?

Comment: @marco_gorelli yea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better if you could provide some code which allows us to reproduce at least part of your DataFrame, such as this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['6254', '5854, 5676, 7265, 6051', '5815']})
```

At the start, your dataframe looks like this:

```
                     code
0                    6254
1  5854, 5676, 7265, 6051
2                    5815
```

A possible solution would be to do this:

```
df['code'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ').add_prefix('code')
```

which gives you this:

```
   code5676  code5815  code5854  code6051  code6254  code7265
0          0          0          0          0          1          0
1          1          0          1          1          0          1
2          0          1          0          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ind=df2.columns.tolist().index('Ticker')

x=0

df3=pd.DataFrame(columns=df2.columns.tolist())

for i in df2.values.tolist():

    l1=i[ind].split(';')
    for j in l1:
        x=x+1
        i1=i[:ind]
        i1.extend([j])
        df3.loc[str(x)]=i1
df3
```